Can I remove the finish from my metal bathtub?
My bathtub has a few big spots where the finish is flaking off and I was wondering if it’s possible to just remove the coating altogether to get the enamel or porcelain to show around the whole tub up to the bottom of the wall tiles.
The bottom flaked off part of the tub appears to have a different color under the fiberglass, than the sides of the tub. Also in one of the corners there is some red material showing, will that be a concern. I wanted to get some opinions on here before calling an expert to do the job since I don’t know what I would be doing and I don’t want to make it worse than it already is.
I am able to stick a magnet to the tub.
 

I doubt very much that you have fiberglass over enamel or porcelain.  What's you're seeing is probably the gel coat on the fiberglass coming off or peeling away,

And pictures always help.

please do not create multiple logins on this site

The painted covering is coming off your porcelain tub. It may be enamel, but looks like it could be inferior paint.  You may be able to strip the paint all off and get it professionally coated with a ceramic coating.

See if a magnet sticks to the tub, and [edit] your question with the result of that. The red area strongly suggests it's steel or cast iron, not fiberglass. Presumably the original porcelain finish was damaged enough that recoating was attempted, and the recoating has failed.

Please tour the help and get your two accounts merged.

Fiberglass is, as the name suggests, glass fibers, usually embedded in resin. In a fiberglass tub it forms the structure of the tub, not the finished surface. You have something else. If you had fiberglass you'd see and feel the glass, assuming you dug deep enough.

I recently had my tub reglazed.  As others have noted in the comments, this doesn't look fiberglass but like paint (the glazing).  The reglazing process is much like doing body work on a car or painting over drywall.
They strip off all the old glaze/paint if they can (my tub was iron or steel, so that was straightforward; if your tub is fiberglass or porcelain, it may be different).  They put down filler and smooth it.  They spray paint (glaze).  They tell you to leave it alone for several days and then take down all the taped cover and replace any fixtures that were removed (the drain cover and switch in my case).  The glaze is oil-based, and the gasses need to be vented.
If you go with someone with experience, that person should be able to advise you on whether reglazing will work for you.  For some tub materials, you might be better off replacing or putting an insert into the tub.

Had our old (70+ years) cast iron tub reglazed this same way.  It helps a lot with the odors if there's a window that can be left opened.
